# Objective-C How to restrict text field to only allow a specific character after 2 inputs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a text field where I'm supposed to only allow 2 digit numbers with a max of 2 decimals (for example 25.50). I want to restrict the input of the 3 character. In my case if there are 2 inputs and none of them is a period "." it should ONLY allow a period for the third input.

I am using a numpad keyboard for this text field which means that the only inputs available are numbers 0 to 9 and a period, you can see that in the uploaded screenshot.

[image: app screenshot]

Below is the code that i use for other restrictions and the part where i assume the code needs to go for my need. Everything else works properly.

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)sender shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string{


//set to possibly restrict the character .
NSMutableCharacterSet *mcs1 = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[mcs1 addCharactersInString:@"."];
NSMutableCharacterSet *mcs2 = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] mutableCopy];/    
[mcs2 addCharactersInString:@"123456789"];

// allow only one period to be inserted
NSRange temprange = [sender.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    if ((temprange.location != NSNotFound) && [string isEqualToString:@"."])
    {
        return NO;
    }

// allow to use backspace and overlap code below
if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return YES;
}



// a max of 5 characters
if(sender.text.length == 5){

    return NO;
}
// if there are 2 inputs and none of them is a period
if(sender.text.length == 2 && [sender.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:mcs1].location == NSNotFound) {

    // NEEDED CODE
    }

// allow only 2 decimal places after a period
NSString *newString = [sender.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if([sep count] >= 2)
{
    NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
    return !([sepStr length]>2);
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: use regex or float validation depend on your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for my problem. I modified your suggestion and it now works with all the other restrictions I have currently working. The `ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS` is defined in a different class where I have all of my constants. Thanks a lot :)

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"."     
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)sender shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string{

//set to possibly restrict the character .
NSMutableCharacterSet *mcs1 = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[mcs1 addCharactersInString:@"."];

// allow only one period to be inserted
NSRange temprange = [sender.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    if ((temprange.location != NSNotFound) && [string isEqualToString:@"."])
    {
        return NO;
    }

// allow to use backspace and overlap code below
if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return YES;
}

// allow only a period as the third input
    if (sender.text.length < 2 || string.length == 0){
    return YES;
}
else if (sender.text.length == 2 && [sender.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:mcs1].location == NSNotFound){

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];

}

// a max of 5 characters (not needed but it should stay)
if(sender.text.length == 5){

    return NO;
}


// allow only 2 decimal places after a period

NSString *newString = [sender.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if([sep count] >= 2)
    {
    NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
    return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For you

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == txtEmailAdd) // Change with your TextField object {
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

        if (newLength == 3 && ![textField.text containsString:@"."]) {
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", textField.text];
        }
        else if (newLength == 3 && [textField.text containsString:@"."]) {
            textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
        }

        return newLength <=5;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of a solution made by my edits and someones recommendations.

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"."     
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)sender shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string{

//set to possibly restrict the character .
NSMutableCharacterSet *mcs1 = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[mcs1 addCharactersInString:@"."];

// allow only one period to be inserted
NSRange temprange = [sender.text rangeOfString:@"."];

if ((temprange.location != NSNotFound) && [string isEqualToString:@"."])
{
    return NO;
}

// allow to use backspace and overlap code below
if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
return YES;
}

// allow only a period as the third input
if (sender.text.length < 2 || string.length == 0){
return YES;
}
else if (sender.text.length == 2 && [sender.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:mcs1].location == NSNotFound){

NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];

NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

return [string isEqualToString:filtered];

}

// a max of 5 characters (not needed but it should stay)
if(sender.text.length == 5){

return NO;
}


// allow only 2 decimal places after a period

NSString *newString = [sender.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if([sep count] >= 2)
{
NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
return !([sepStr length]>2);
}
```